# Can I provide different animations for entry and exit of fragments in ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have created a viewpager with 5 fragments with custom animations. It has been an easy task so far. Now challenge starts. I have to implement different entry and exit animations for all the fragments inside the viewpager. Each fragment can have different animations for the way it enters the screen and exits the screen. I have not found any solution yet. This is what i have done so far but obviously, it just shows single animation throughout.

### In the Activity

```
mViewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new ViewPagerAnimation(ViewPagerAnimation
                .AnimationType.FLIP));
```

### In ViewPagerAnimation Class

```
public class ViewPagerAnimation implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

  public enum AnimationType {
    FLIP,
    SCALE_IN_OUT
  }

  private static final float MIN_SCALE_DEPTH = 0.75f;
  private static final float MIN_SCALE_ZOOM = 0.85f;
  private static final float MIN_ALPHA_ZOOM = 0.5f;
  private static final float SCALE_FACTOR_SLIDE = 0.85f;
  private static final float MIN_ALPHA_SLIDE = 0.35f;
  private static final float MIN_FLIP_CUBE_PIVOT = 0.5f;
  private static final float MIN_FLOW_ROTATION = 30f;

  private final AnimationType mAnimationType;

  public ViewPagerAnimation(AnimationType animationType) {
    mAnimationType = animationType;
  }

  public void transformPage(View pageView, float position) {

    switch (mAnimationType) {
      case FLIP:
        setFlipAnimation(pageView, position);
        break;
      case SCALE_IN_OUT:
        setScaleInOutAnimation(pageView, position);
        break;
      default:
    }
  }

  private void setFlipAnimation(View pageView, float position) {
    final float rotation = 180f * position;

    pageView.setAlpha(rotation > 90f || rotation < -90f ? 0 : 1);
    pageView.setPivotX(pageView.getWidth() * MIN_FLIP_CUBE_PIVOT);
    pageView.setPivotY(pageView.getHeight() * MIN_FLIP_CUBE_PIVOT);
    pageView.setRotationY(rotation);
  }

  private void setScaleInOutAnimation(View pageView, float position) {
    pageView.setPivotX(position < 0 ? 0 : pageView.getWidth());
    pageView.setPivotY(pageView.getHeight() / 2f);
    float scale = position < 0 ? 1f + position : 1f - position;
    pageView.setScaleX(scale);
    pageView.setScaleY(scale);
  }

}
```

Comment: you can, but you will have to animate fragments manually. View pager has a listener for page selected, which provides callback method to track scrolling, so you can take current scroll progress, and transform fragment's view based on it.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko  Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it but animations started to show some strange behaviour. I felt like animations are intermixing.

Comment: Is there any way to do that? Please reply...

Comment: `I tried it but` probably you did something wrong. `Is there any way to do that` the way I suggested in 1st comment